# How to use MyBatis to iterate all fields of an object?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis

I want to insert all fields of a object to a row, but I don't know the exact filed names. Does MyBatis support this?

Comment: Please give an example of your class and your table columns

Comment: Please add some code of your's so that I can give you some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mybatis uses [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html) in places where expression is expected including `collection` attribute of the `foreach`.

OGNL [allows](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Calling_Static_Methods) to invoke static methods so you can leverage this.

With default scripting engine (assuming that properties names match column names) you can do something like this to generate the list of fields:

```
<bind name="objectProperties"
  value="@org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils@describe(myParameter).entrySet()" />

INSERT INTO mytable (
  <foreach index="propertyName" item="propertyValue"
    collection="objectProperties" separator=",">
        ${propertyName}
  </foreach>
)
VALUES (
  <foreach index="propertyName" item="propertyValue"
    collection="objectProperties" separator=",">
        @{propertyValue}
  </foreach>
)
```

Note that this was not tested and is here just to demonstrate the idea how you can approach this.

I personally haven't used `foreach` as I prefer to use [velocity scripting engine](http://www.mybatis.org/velocity-scripting/). With velocity scripting engine this can definitely be done:

```
#set( $objectProperties = $BeanUtils.describe($myParameter) )

INSERT INTO mytable (
  #foreach($property in $objectProperties)
    ${property.key}
  #end
)
VALUES (
  #foreach($property in $objectProperties)
    @{property.value}
  #end
)
```

You would also need to add reference to commons `BeanUtils` class to velocity context by adding this configuration to `mybatis-velocity.properties`:

```
additional.context.attributes=BeanUtils:org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should using the SQL statement `select into` to complete this requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Your answer would be improved by showing some example code. The question is specifically about MyBatis and I wonder if your answer addresses this.

Answer (score -1):

your pojo`s properties should  be consistent with the table`s columns, and the autoMapping should be true. maybe you have to give some codes of your project,So I'll give you more advice

Comment: How is `autoMapping` related to insert?

Comment: thanks for your reminder, the autoMapping  is not related to insert